# Hubspot: stage entire website including primary CSS file during website redesign

Tags: hubspot

I am helping a client redesign their website through Hubspot. Their existing site is within Hubspot and their new website will also be within Hubspot. I am attempting to run the development through Hubspot's Content Staging as per this link: https://knowledge.hubspot.com/website-user-guide/how-to-redesign-and-relaunch-your-site-with-content-staging

The problem is that this appears to be on a per page basis rather than a per site basis. A problem with this is that I am unable to stage files such as the primary CSS file, or other CSS/JS files that I need to make changes to, but that the existing website will need to keep untouched throughout development.

Does anyone have any experience redesigning a Hubspot website who may have some advise for me? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I'm redeveloping a HubSpot site within a client's portal, i'll do it on a template by template basis.

So for example, if you're making a new home page, just attach any stylesheets and scripts you need in the template file itself - found in the `Edit > Edit Head` menu. Here you can disable the `Primary CSS` file, and you can also disable `domain specific` stylesheets (the ones you add in `Content > Content Settings`) so that your template is only using the assets you want it to use.

Using this technique, you can work on individual templates, and then stage any pages that are using said templates independently of the rest of the website. Finally when you're ready to make your changes site wide, merely move your assets from the `Edit head` area within your template to the `Content Settings` area.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I have started doing and it is working well.